# How to add parameters to the homepage URL in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a single flow Bootstrap template with all the sections like "About", "Contact" and others as part of a single file. The problem comes with the menu bar as I am using django's inheritance for templates to include the menu bar(declared in home_menubar.html) and I use the line `{% include 'home/home_menubar.html' %}` in all my webpages for the menu bar.

The problem is I had to declare specific urls for all the categories in the menu bar so as to render the same HTML file for displaying a particular section in the page like if I want to visit the about column. the url would be `localhost:8000/about/#aboutus`

That URL looks is sickening me. Is there any way the URL would become `localhost:8000/#aboutus` ??

**Update 1:** I use the `home_menubar.html` file in many webpages like login.html, register.html etc. So if I issued

About

, then in this URL: `localhost:8000/login/` and About menu item is clicked, it becomes `localhost:8000/login/#about` which DOES NOT exist.

Some code:

**home_menubar.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans';">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="{% url 'web_root' %}" class="navbar-brand"><img src="{% static 'home/images/logo.png' %}" alt="company logo" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right custom-menu">
                <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'benefits' %}">Benefits</a></li>
                {% ifnotequal events_obj None %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'upevents' %}">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                {%endifnotequal%}
                <li><a href="{% url 'contactus' %}">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**views.py:**

```
def show_homepage(request):
        return render(request,'home/homepage.html')

def view_about(request):
        return render(request,'home/homepage.html',{'goto':'about'})

def view_benefits(request):
        return render(request,'home/homepage.html',{'goto':'benefits'})

def view_upevents(request):
        return render(request,'home/homepage.html',{'goto':'upevents'})
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^$', views.show_homepage,name="web_root"),
    url(r'^benefits/', views.view_benefits,name="benefits"),
    url(r'^upevents/', views.view_upevents,name="upevents"),
    url(r'^about/', views.view_about,name="about"),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you're duplicating views at all...

Why not just have a single home page view:

```
def show_homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'home/homepage.html')
```

With an accompanying URL:

```
url(r'^$', views.show_homepage, name="web_root"),
```

And then in *home_menubar.html*:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right custom-menu">
    <li><a href="/#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#benefits">Benefits</a></li>
    {% ifnotequal events_obj None %}
    <li><a href="/#upevents">Upcoming Events</a></li>
    {%endifnotequal%}
    <li><a href="/#contactus">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: would it work in **any** webpage I include the template file to? like login page or something?

Comment: I have updated the code so that it will work in that scenario. Alternatively, you can use the following to ensure it will work everywhere: `<a href="{% url 'web_root' %}#about">About</a>`

Comment: that did it. Thank you so much.